# Boolean operators (and, or) in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Here is a quote from http://www.braveclojure.com/:

> Clojure uses the Boolean operators `or` and `and`. `or` returns either the first truthy value or the last value. `and` returns the first falsey value or, if no values are falsey, the last truthy value.

Why do you build something like that into the language? How often do you come across use cases for it?

Comment: All the time in practical and idiomatic expressions.

Comment: Suggest you rephrase your final paragraph to something like *What are they for?*.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit different than other languages, but is sometimes handy for default values.  For example:

```
(defn print-it [x] 
  (println (or x :unknown)))

> (print-it 5)
5

> (print-it "hi")
hi

> (print-it false)
:unknown

> (print-it nil)
:unknown
```

So for a normal value like `5` or `"hi"`, the result of the `or` expression is the supplied value.  If the value is `nil` (or `false`), the default value `:unknown` is returned.